# ASP.Net Unable to find .Net Framework Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, visual-studio, connection-string

During the process of uploading a site to a Godaddy server, the datagrid using MySql is causing problems.  The errors are outputted below along with the web config.  The issue seems to be that the server does not have the proper installed requirements such as the MySql.Data in my web config, but I am unsure what to do.  The .Net MySql connector is installed on the local system and runs fine.  Here's the error outputted.

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web           request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it   originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework    Data Provider.  It may not be installed.


[ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not   be installed.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +1419911
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.GetDbProviderFactory() +67
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.GetDbProviderFactorySecure() +22
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.CreateConnection(String connectionString) +11
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments   arguments) +117
 System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
  System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
  System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
  System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean     includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

Web Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
```

```
<add name="GoDaddy" connectionString=" Server=***; Database=kappalambda; User ID=***; Password=***; Trusted_Connection=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />



<!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial  Catalog=aspnet-Kappa Lambda-20130125180802;Integrated  Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Kappa Lambda-20130125180802.mdf"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />     
         -->
   <add name="noahtk_DirectoryKappaSigAppConnectionString"  connectionString="server=***;User  Id=noahtk_klofks;password=***;database=***"
   providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />




  <!--  <add name="liveConnection" connectionString="server=****; User     Id=***; password=****#; database=****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>  
   -->

  </connectionStrings>
```

```
</authentication>

<profile defaultProvider="Godaddy">
  <providers>
    <add name="Godaddy" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="Godaddy" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="Godaddy">
  <providers>
```

```
   <!--
        If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
        you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
        change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
        of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to bin-deploy the data provider. [This](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6639/do-your-hosting-accounts-support-mvc3-applications) link from GoDaddy describes how to bin-deploy ASP.NET MVC dll's but the process should be similar for the MySQL DLL you have which contains the data provider (i.e. copy-local should be set to true).

Sorry if I'm not on the right track.

HTH,
Nathan

Comment: Close, but I think the webconfig needs something as well.

Comment: Perhaps the answer at the bottom of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887486/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-it-may-not-be-instal) could help?

Comment: Hi does this server support mysql server?

Comment: Yes, the server supports MySql.